# Can i remove schema.rb in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment

Is this file for informational purposes ?

Can it be removed in production ?

Comment: Any particular reason you'd actually want to remove it?

Comment: I want to remove it, because i never use in at production server side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `schema.rb` is used when you execute `rake db:schema:load`. If you are **absolutely sure** you are not going to execute this Rake task in production, then **yes**, you could remove it.

I'm unsure why you'd want to take the time to remove it explicitly, though.